# How do I read/print the contents within a blob storage container?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to read the contents within "clients" blob storage.

As you can see in the attached picture, I have listed the blobs within that container and now I would like to print the contents of the blobs. for example, I trying to print out the contents of a json file called "clients.json"

```
import os, uuid, json
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
from config import config, store

try:
        print("Azure Blob Storage v" + __version__ + " - Python quickstart sample")
        configConnectionString = config
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(configConnectionString)

        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(store)
        
        # List the blobs in the container
        # blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
        # for blob in blob_list:
        #     print("\t" + blob.name)
        
        # Read the contents within the blob containers 
        with open('clients.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)   
            print(data)  
            
except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:')
        print(ex)
```

[this is to show that my code is working when I want to list the blobs in the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe2sm.png)

Answer (score 0):

The *`get_container_client`* return an instance of *[`ContainerClient` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python)*. It has  a method called *[`download_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#download-blob-blob--offset-none--length-none----kwargs-)* which can be used to download the blob to the *[`StorageStreamDownloader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python)*. You can then use the *[`content_as_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.storagestreamdownloader?view=azure-python#content-as-text-max-concurrency-1--encoding--utf-8--)* method of the *`StorageStreamDownloader`* class to download the contents of the blob, and decode as text.

```
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(store)
downloader = container_client.download_blob("clients.json")
print(downloader.content_as_text())
```

Comment: are these built-in functions available for node js?